# Foreach - verificar e gravar somente os que não estão no BD

Tags: php, mysql

Dentro de um foreach preciso fazer um insert no meu banco de dados somente dos registros que não estiverem gravados, evitando assim duplicidade de registros, mas não consegui imaginar uma solução para verificar se um registro está gravado no banco e se estiver ignorar e verificar o próximo, o que tenho é isso:

```
    // Recebendo o array com os ID´S
$checkboxes = $_POST['check'];  

// laço para buscar ID´s e efetuar cadastro
foreach($checkboxes as $IdColaborador) {

    $IdTreinamento = $_POST['IdTreinamento'];

    // Verificando se Treinamento e Colaborador já existe 
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsVerifica = "SELECT * FROM treParticipantesTreinamento WHERE IdTreinamento = $IdTreinamento AND IdColaborador = $IdColaborador";
    $rsVerifica = mysql_query($query_rsVerifica, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsVerifica = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsVerifica);
    $totalRows_rsVerifica = mysql_num_rows($rsVerifica);

    // Buscando dados do Colaborador
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT * FROM comColaborador WHERE IdColaborador = $IdColaborador AND ativo = 1";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($row_rsRegistro);

    // Buscando dados do Treinamento                
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsTreinamento = "SELECT * FROM treTreinamento WHERE IdTreinamento = $IdTreinamento";
    $rsTreinamento = mysql_query($query_rsTreinamento, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsTreinamento = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTreinamento); 
    $totalRows_rsTreinamento = mysql_num_rows($row_rsTreinamento);

    // Dados do Colaborador
    $Nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    // Dados do Treinamento
    $Horas = $row_rsTreinamento['CargaHoraria'];
    $FezTreinamento = 0;    
    $Log = $row_rsTreinamento['Log'];       

    // Inserindo dados no banco de dados se não existir cadastro        
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $sqlTreinamento = "INSERT INTO treParticipantesTreinamento ( 
                    IdTreinamento, 
                    IdColaborador,
                    Nome,
                    Horas,
                    FezTreinamento,
                    Log ) 
                VALUES (
                    '$IdTreinamento', 
                    '$IdColaborador',
                    '$Nome',                        
                    '$Horas',   
                    '$FezTreinamento',                      
                    '$Log')";                               
    $resultado = mysql_query($sqlTreinamento, $conexao) or die ("Erro Inserindo Registro: " . mysql_error());

    // 1 = TRUE, 2 = FALSE
    $status = $resultado;       

} // fim do foreach*/
```

Comment: Duas opções, usar o `REPLACE` no lugar do `INSERT` ou fazer uma consulta comparando os dados que não podem ser repetidos e se resultar registros dar um `continue` no foreach...

Comment: Olá @Jader, tem como me dar um exemplo do comando Continue? Valeu.

Comment: algo assim após a consulta: `if ($num_rows > 0) continue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
    // Recebendo o array com os ID´S
    $checkboxes = $_POST['check'];  

    $IdTreinamento = $_POST['IdTreinamento'];    

    // Verificando os Colaboradores existente 

    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsVerifica = "SELECT * FROM treParticipantesTreinamento WHERE IdTreinamento = $IdTreinamento";
    $rsVerifica = mysql_query($query_rsVerifica, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $totalRows_rsVerifica = mysql_num_rows($rsVerifica);
    $trePT = Array();
    if ($totalRows_rsVerifica > 0)
       while ($row_rsVerifica = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsVerifica)) $trePT[] = $row_rsVerifica['IdColaborador'];



// laço para buscar ID´s e efetuar cadastro
foreach($checkboxes as $IdColaborador) {

    // Se colaborador existir passa para próximo
    if (in_array($IdColaborador, $trePT)) continue;

    // Buscando dados do Colaborador
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT * FROM comColaborador WHERE IdColaborador = $IdColaborador AND ativo = 1";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($row_rsRegistro);

    // Buscando dados do Treinamento                
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsTreinamento = "SELECT * FROM treTreinamento WHERE IdTreinamento = $IdTreinamento";
    $rsTreinamento = mysql_query($query_rsTreinamento, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsTreinamento = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTreinamento); 
    $totalRows_rsTreinamento = mysql_num_rows($row_rsTreinamento);

    // Dados do Colaborador
    $Nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    // Dados do Treinamento
    $Horas = $row_rsTreinamento['CargaHoraria'];
    $FezTreinamento = 0;    
    $Log = $row_rsTreinamento['Log'];       

    // Inserindo dados no banco de dados se não existir cadastro        
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $sqlTreinamento = "INSERT INTO treParticipantesTreinamento ( 
                    IdTreinamento, 
                    IdColaborador,
                    Nome,
                    Horas,
                    FezTreinamento,
                    Log ) 
                VALUES (
                    '$IdTreinamento', 
                    '$IdColaborador',
                    '$Nome',                        
                    '$Horas',   
                    '$FezTreinamento',                      
                    '$Log')";                               
    $resultado = mysql_query($sqlTreinamento, $conexao) or die ("Erro Inserindo Registro: " . mysql_error());

    // 1 = TRUE, 2 = FALSE
    $status = $resultado;       

} // fim do foreach*/
```

Comment: Olá @Carlos, só fiz uma alteração, coloquei a sua verificação inicial dentro do meu foreach, pois não tinha como pegar o ID do colaborador e ai ficou perfeito, valeu pela grande ajuda.

Comment: Opa @adventistapr beleza, na verdade era pra mim ter retirado o ` AND IdColaborador = $IdColaborador` que ai não precisa ficar fazendo mais uma consulta dentro do loop, corrigi ali, veja se funciona ai.

Comment: Isso é realmente verdade, valeu pela ajuda e preciosa ajuda @Carlos.

Answer (score -1):

Evite a utilização das funções mysql_* pois as mesmas estão em processo de descontinuação.
Ao invés disso utilize PDO ou mysqli.

Um exemplo de otimização do seu código seria utilizando prepared statements:

```
$conn = new PDO('connstr', 'usuario','senha');
$prepared = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comColaborador WHERE IdColaborador = :ID AND ativo = 1");

foreach($checkboxes as $IdColaborador) {
  $prepared->bindValue(':ID', $idColaborador, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $exec = $prepared->execute();
}
```

Com a técnica acima você 'prepara' a consulta de funcionário apenas uma vez no banco e muda apenas seu parametro para cada funcionário. Isto tornará o código bem mais rápido.